# Is Android development specialized enough to split it off from SO?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

I see many questions that are Android specific in SO. Being a very popular platform, it might make sense to split it off.

Comment: What benefit would that have? Then you're just splitting a community of programmers that may not be specific to Android programming. Not everyone *only* codes in one language.

Comment: what about ios and other .. split them all ?

Comment: I see many questions that are [insert your favorite platform here] specific in SO.  Being a very popular platform, it might make sense to split it off.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you ruined the fun of pasting 20 identical comments each with a different language

Comment: Are you aware of area51? take a look: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current system of allowing a category tag  [android](/questions/tagged/android) can help you accomplish what you seek. The advantage of having one board with Android *and* other topics (like those relating to Java, Python, user experience, design, tools related, etc) is that you can start with an "Android" question that may lead you to other areas for the resolution or information you seek.

We do need to help (see meta) ensure that tags and combinations to remain useful as work evolves, and you can help that too!